# Value not incrementing in mongoose when creating a new object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack

Here is my code, I want to increment the total no of counts as soon as any user gives the rating. But the $inc command is not running and result is showing the default value which I set zero.

The given is my Schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Rating = new schema({
    user_id:{
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    },
    stars:{
        type:Number
    },
    ratingCount:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    }
})

const rating = mongoose.model('Rating', Rating);
module.exports = rating;
```

This is the function where I want to increment the value.

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();

let Rating = require('../model/rating');

Router.route('/add/:userid').post((req,res)=>{

    new Rating({
        user_id: req.params.userid,
        $inc: {ratingCount:1},
        stars: req.body.stars
    })
    .save()
    .then(rating=>res.send(rating))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));

});


module.exports = Router;
```

Result showing default value of ratingCount.

[image]

Comment: Please do not include pictures, have code in text format !! Do you wanna set `req.body.stars` to `stars` & inc `ratingCount` at sametime ?

Comment: yes thats what I want

Comment: I have updated the format

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use `.save()` instead you can simply use [.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/index.html) with option `{ new: true }` to return updated document, if it doesn't find any matching document `.findOneAndUpdate()` will return `null`.

**Code :**

```
const express = require("express");
const Router = express.Router();
let Rating = require("../model/rating");
Router.route("/add/:userid").post((req, res) => {
  Rating.findOneAndUpdate(
    { user_id: req.params.userid },
    { $inc: { ratingCount: 1 }, stars: req.body.stars },
    { new: true }
  )
    .then((rating) => res.send(rating))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
module.exports = Router;
```

Usually `.save()` will track changes to document which is returned from find call. Otherwise if it's not the mongoose document returned from `.find()` call if it's the mongoose object which you're forming like what you're doing now then if it finds `_id` in object it will update the matching doc else if no matching doc exists with `_id` or no `_id` present in request it will insert the new document.